# How to write the Style for check box place in the GridCell UWP?

Tags: datagrid, uwp, styles, uwp-xaml, syncfusion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5fnE.png)

I have tried to write the style for check box placed in the Grid cell by setting the target type as checkbox, but its apply the style also for the filter checkbox. could anybody suggest me to write the style only for the Grid cell check box.
Please find the image attached above i have write a style only for the checkbox loaded in the grid cell instead of the applying to all

I tried it by this way

```
 <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <my:SfDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" AllowFiltering="True" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Could you post some code please of what you have tried? *Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program!* http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's very strange. I used your code to test in my side. There's no any effects in my side. No matter checkBox in cell or in filterControl, they all have no red background.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Column` property of `DataGridCell` and check its `DisplayIndex` value and write a `DataTrigger`.

Sample approach :

```
  <DataGrid ...>
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridCell, Mode=FindAncestor}}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Hi Anjum, Thanks for look in to my query, Could you please share the suggestion for this query in UWP..

Comment: OP isn't talking about a `DataGrid`.  Besides, the only UWP `DataGrid` is the [Community](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid) version which does not support `<Style.Triggers>`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. @BalamuruganR I've made a simple code sample for you. Using the GridTemplateColumn and specify a "x:Key" for your custom style. Please check the following code sample:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="cellTemplate">
        <CheckBox  Content="DataGrid"  IsChecked="{Binding Flag}" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}"></CheckBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <syncfusion:SfDataGrid x:Name="sfGrid" Grid.Column="0"
                               AllowGrouping="True"
                               AutoExpandGroups="True"
                               ShowGroupDropArea="True"
                               AllowEditing="True"
                               AllowFiltering="True"
                               AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding UserDetails}">
        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
            <syncfusion:GridTextColumn MappingName="UserId" />
            <syncfusion:GridTextColumn MappingName="Name" />
            <syncfusion:GridDateTimeColumn MappingName="DateofBirth" />
            <syncfusion:GridNumericColumn MappingName="ContactNo" />
            <syncfusion:GridTemplateColumn MappingName="Flag" CellTemplate="{StaticResource cellTemplate}" />
        </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>
    </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: HI Anjum , In your provided code sample the style is applied for whole content in the cell. But my query is to apply the style only for the checkbox not for whole cell.